File Upload Icon changes, is possible to use old one? [DevExpres Blazor]
A recent devexpress blazor resource update has unexpectedly altered the appearance of the file upload icon (DxUpload).
I update the version from 23.2.6 to 24.1.5-pre-24217.
Before:

After:

There is a way to keep the old version view, with bigger document icon and the extension label (without rollback to previous version)?
